# Oracle Database Control username and password

Tags: oracle11g

I've installed Oracle Database 11g on Windows 7, and when I open the `Database Control`, I get this page :

[image]

In the installation I choosed orcl as Username and orcl as Password, but when I enter them I get that the the username and/or password are invalid.

How can I solve this problem ?

Comment: Can you login as SYSMAN?

Answer (score 5):

Log in to the database using the user name SYS and connect as SYSDBA.

Use the password that you specified for the SYS account during the installation.

for further info follow this link

http://docs.oracle.com/cd/B19306_01/install.102/b15660/rev_precon_db.htm

Comment: Thanks, this allows me to log in. I wonder how can we log in with other usernames because logging in with other usernames will result in `invalid username and/or password`.

Answer (score 0):

This problem happens due to deprecated **OracleDBConsoleSID** startup.

Use:

```
emctl stop dbconsole

emctl start dbconsole
```

Then close the tab and open EM URL in new tab.
Use your SYS credential to log in.